# how to continue processing even though encountered file not found in a loop?

Tags: java, exception

```
System.out.println("Please enter the required word  :");
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
   String word = scan.nextLine();
   String [] array = word.split(" ");
   int filename = 500;
   String[] fileName = new String [filename];
   int a = 0;



   try
   {
   for(a=0; a<filename; a++)
   {

       File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\TextRenderer\\abc" + a + ".txt");
       System.out.println("File = abc" + a + ".txt");
        for( int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {

   System.out.println(array[i]);

   int totalCount = 0;
   int wordCount = 0;
   Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
   {
   while (s.hasNext()) 
   {
   totalCount++;
   if (s.next().equals(array[i])) wordCount++;

   }

   System.out.println("Word count:  " + wordCount);
   System.out.println("Total count: " + totalCount); 
   System.out.printf("Term Frequency:   %8.4f", (double) wordCount / totalCount);
```

the output :

File = abc4.txt

a
Word count:  2
Total count: 119
Term Frequency:     0.0168

about
Word count:  0
Total count: 119
Term Frequency:     0.0000

the
Word count:  3
Total count: 119
Term Frequency:     0.0252

File = abc5.txt
a
Word count:  4
Total count: 141
Term Frequency:     0.0284

about
Word count:  0
Total count: 141
Term Frequency:     0.0000

the
Word count:  2
Total count: 141
Term Frequency:     0.0142

File = abc6.txt

a
File is not found

after the a specific file is not found, the code stops. How to make it to proceed to other file ? This code has 2 additional files to process but it stops when encountered file not found. Any advices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should catch for the exception inside your loop like so

```
 for(a=0; a<filename; a++)
   {
     try{
       Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
     }catch{FileNotFoundException e){ 
      // handle the exception
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your try/catch inside your for loop.

Specifically,  you want to only wrap it around the attempt to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `try{..} catch ()` (see [sun tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet appears incomplete, but it looks like you have a try/catch pair around the for loop. You might want another try/catch block inside the for loop. You can have it catch FileNotFoundException or a more general exception and allow the loop to continue without breaking.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not continuing on is the exception breaks the loop since it is caught outside of the loop. You need to put (or move) the try/catch block inside of the loop.

```
for(a=0; a<filename; a++) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```